# How to save console output to string in crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

On ruby I can do

```
require "stringio"
def with_captured_stdout
  begin
    old_stdout = $stdout
    $stdout = StringIO.new('','w')
    yield
    $stdout.string
  ensure
    $stdout = old_stdout
  end
end
```

and later call it like

```
str = with_captured_stdout { Solution.main("Greetings from Javatlacati") }
```

but on [crystal-lang](/questions/tagged/crystal-lang) I can refer to global variable `$stdout` without getting the corresponding error

> $global_variables are not supported, use @@class_variables instead

is there any workaround? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there's no easy way to capture stdout or stderr in the crystal standard library, however here's a shard which looks to do that: https://github.com/mosop/stdio.